# Converting days since Jan.1 1900 to today's date

Tags: c, date, datetime, logic

```
typedef struct dbdatetime
{                       // Internal representation of DATETIME data type
LONG  dtdays;       // No of days since Jan-1-1900 (maybe negative)
ULONG dttime;       // No. of 300 hundredths of a second since midnight
} DBDATETIME;
```

I am trying to convert this struct into today's date. I don't suspect the time will give me much trouble but I am having problems with the logic of converting the total number of days to the proper month and day.

Ex. Friday November 7th is 41948 days.

You can divide by 365.2425+1900 to get the current year but how would you get the proper month / date.

Does C have anything built in to handle this? I am not a C programmer by trade.

Comment: You definitely don't want to do this by hand. It's exceedingly tricky to get right and there are lots of edge cases. I don't remember the library function to call, but that's what you need to do.

Comment: Should you want to roll you own code - an interesting task - pretend the year ends in February.  (it used to end in February about 2000 years ago. _Octo_ber was the 8th month,  _Dece_mber was the 10th month.)  and leap day is then at the end of the year.  Suggest calculating to/from March 1, 2000

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the C standard directly to handle this, but if you are willing to write OS specific code, or can import libraries like `boost::date_time`, this is the best option. Don't attempt to handle it yourself unless you are okay with edge cases being wrong. Dates and times are notoriously difficult to get right.

Here are the docs for `date_time` which can do arithmetic on dates, including "add N days to 1/1/1900". http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html#date_time.gregorian.date_duration

```
date d(1900, Jan, 1)
d += days(dtdays);
```

**EDIT:** OP can't use boost, but I'll leave this here in case a future visitor could use the info.

Comment: "Nothing in the C standard to handle this"?  You mean like [`mktime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/mktime) and friends?

Comment: As for boost, the question is tagged C.

Comment: `mktime` returns a `time_t` which (a) is implementation defined how it works, and (b) in common implementations is seconds since 1970. I don't see how you'd actually implement his request using it.

Comment: You're right that if C++ is restricted, he can't use boost, but he didn't specifically say C++ was disallowed. In general it should be easy to use boost in an otherwise C-only code base. Just keep it in its own compilation unit.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you can divide the number of days by 365.2425 to get a approx estimation of the year. Once you have that, use the number of years and leap years between 1900 and that year to calculate the number of days till that year.

You need to make sure that the logic for detecting leap years is sound. Once you know which years are leap years, you'll be fine. For example, 1900 is NOT a leap year, even though it is divisible by 4. Google leap year rules to find out why.

Once you have that, the remaining days will belong to the current year. Use the leap year logic again to determine whether you the current year is leap or not. Then on it's just a matter of counting days for each month.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is out of the question, thanks for all the input guys.

I did find this algorithm that seems to work so far but am testing it now.

```
int l = nSerialDate + 68569 + 2415019;
int n = int(( 4 * l ) / 146097);
        l = l - int(( 146097 * n + 3 ) / 4);
int i = int(( 4000 * ( l + 1 ) ) / 1461001);
    l = l - int(( 1461 * i ) / 4) + 31;
int j = int(( 80 * l ) / 2447);
 nDay = l - int(( 2447 * j ) / 80);
    l = int(j / 11);
    nMonth = j + 2 - ( 12 * l );
nYear = 100 * ( n - 49 ) + i + l;
```

Trying to find some theory behind it now.

Comment: Ya this algorithm is close but doesn't appear to work fully. 41948 is returning: 11/5/2014 not 11/7/2014

Comment: BTW: If you choose to use MS Excel to check your work note 2 things: 1) Jan 1, 1900 is day 1 (not the number of days _since_ Jan 1, 1900) and 2) according to Excel Feb 29, 1900 exists(a bug in their code they refuse to fix.)

Comment: This would essentially throw everything off by 1 day correct? I did some reading up this apparently had to do with wanting the ability to import Lotus 1 2 3 files.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the input everyone, here is what I ended up doing.

1. Convert dtdays to seconds, minus the offset of the number of seconds between Jan-1-1900(Serial Date) and Jan-1-1970(UNIX Time). Which is 2208988800, this leaves us with UNIX time.
2. Convert the hundredths of seconds into seconds and add to the total.
3. Convert UNIX time using gmtime() to a tm struct.