# How to calculate days since 1900 generated by excel date?

Tags: excel, go

Excel is converting the date 03/11/2021 to value 44535, which seems to be days since 1900. I´m trying to figure out a way to calculate this using my own golang libs. Does anyone have this kind of problem?

Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: This is more complicated than you might think. For instance, [many countries have changed calendars after 1900](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adoption_dates_of_the_Gregorian_calendar_by_country). At the very least you have to find out how Excel deals with this.

Comment: Do check out Excel help and the 1904 date system, especially if you use an older version of Excel with a Mac or get files from people who do.

Comment: Umm, Not sure I see the problem.  Excel documentation says that all dates are stored as floating point numbers as number of days since 1/1/1900.  Your spreadsheet is FORMATING them as integers.  Just highlight your date column, go to Format Numbers, and choose a Date format instead of Number format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A not so fency workaround for this problem would be *addDays*

```
d := time.Date(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
fmt.Println(d) // 1900-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC

d2 := d.AddDate(0, 0, 44503)
fmt.Println(d2) // 2021-11-05 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

Would print: 05/11/2021 witch is 2 days more than what we desire.

Here we can see the same using JavaScript:

```
date = new Date(1900, 0, 1)
// Mon Jan 01 1900 00:00:00 GMT-0338 (Amazon Standard Time)
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 44503)
// Fri Nov 05 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Amazon Standard Time)
```

After some research about this 2 days I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26792144/converting-days-since-jan-1-1900-to-todays-date) in a comment by @chux-reinstate-monica:

> If you choose to use MS Excel to check your work note 2 things: 1) Jan 1, 1900 is day 1 (not the number of days since Jan 1, 1900) and 2) according to Excel Feb 29, 1900 exists(a bug in their code they refuse to fix.)

So we can substract 2 days from that to have: 03/11/2021.

Comment: code should be text, not screenshot